# Cooling issue with small 0606 SMD LED

Tags: led, surface-mount, heat, cooling

I recently purchased [IR LED](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3214790.pdf) which comes in 0606 package.
LED is of 3W (1A at 3.3v according to datasheet) and certainly require cooling but the problem is that it does not have any space for cooling. Also pads are pretty close to each other.[image]

If no cooling pad is given shoould I use ground pad for cooling ? or should I expose both pads ? or should I expose bottom layer copper beneath the LED and connect it to heat sink but not to any pad ?
Is there any other way to provide cooling for such components ?

Comment: It's probably more suited for aluminum boards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datasheet recommends solder-mask-defined pads with extended copper.

[image]

There are no dimensions given for the extended copper, you can make it as big as possible.

You should also refer to the relevant [application notes](https://www.osram.com/appsn/AppNotes/Web/AppNotes.aspx?show=led)  from OSRAM for design, measurement and design verification purposes.

> Application Notes
>
> The thermal measurement point of LEDs
>
> Package related thermal resistance of LEDs
>
> Temperature measurement with thermocouples
>
> Thermal management of light sources based on SMT LEDs

Even with the relatively high efficiency of that LED a couple watts will be turned into heat at 3W input. That's quite a bit for such a small package- you may need to reduce current, use larger or thicker copper, or use an aluminum core board.

Comment: Those document also suggests large pads so I am going with that with some vias. Thank you for reply.